# How to check if "data packet head" is encrypted by VPN?

Tags: encryption, vpn

I found [here](https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/stop-isp-throttling/):

> Deep Packet Inspection (DPI) allows ISPs to identify the source of data via inference based on the data packet head. A good VPN will protect against this, so even the data packet head is encrypted and anonymized.

Is anywhere a list with VPNs that encrypt the data packet head(s)?

Comment: There is a mismatch between title and body of your question. In the title you ask how to check for it yourself (answer: use a packet sniffer like wireshark) but in the body you ask a for a list or pointer to a list of the VPN which properly hide the original target. In short: probably all VPN which encrypt also hide (encrypt) the original destination. But not everything which is sometimes called a VPN actually encrypts: notably anonymous proxies or similar usually do not encrypt and simple L2TP, IPIP or GRE do not encrypt either.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the mismatch ... .Please, I have 0 experience in using wireshark, I've installed this morning. I will appreciate very much if you are so kind to tell me which is the relevant difference between (1) head encrypted and (2) head not encrypted. How they are differing? How can I see that? Thank you.

Comment: What they likely mean is the IP header of the packet which contains the original destination. Most VPN actually encrypt the whole packet, which also includes the original IP header. I think IPSec has in theory the option to only encrypt the payload - but IPSec is usually not used for this kind of VPN you typically use for privacy anyway, it is used for VPN connecting different locations of a company etc instead. And, if you have no experience with Wireshark then this here is not the place to teach you the basics of wireshark and of networking since these are not about information security.

Comment: Thank you. I am researching and learning this stuff.